# Plotting NOAA data with Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, noaa

I'm very new to Python but have been learning lots over the last few months. I'm trying to plot NOAA swell height data from a grib2 file located here: ftp://ftpprd.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/wave/prod/wave.20140122/nww3.t06z.grib.grib2

I use `Basemap` and a tutorial that I found on a `Basemap` forum.

A minimum working example is below, but I'm getting some strange white boxes around the coastline.

```
import Nio
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f = Nio.open_file('nww3.t12z.grib(2).grib2')
lons = f.variables['lon_0'][:]
lats = f.variables['lat_0'][::-1] # flip latitudes so data goes S-->N
times = f.variables['forecast_time0'][:]
ntime = 5
data = f.variables['HTSGW_P0_L1_GLL0'][ntime,::-1]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-35.,llcrnrlat=42.,urcrnrlon=5.,urcrnrlat=65.,
            projection='lcc',lat_1=10.,lat_2=15.,lon_0=10.,
            resolution ='h',area_thresh=1000.)

x, y = m(*np.meshgrid(lons, lats))
m.fillcontinents(color='#477519')
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5, color='k', antialiased=1, ax=None, zorder=None )

m.contourf(x, y, data, np.arange(0,9.9,0.1))
plt.show()
```

This is the result (the top panel; I would like it to look like the bottom panel): http://oi43.tinypic.com/s2s3m0.jpg

Sorry I don't have enough points to post images.

Thanks in advance,
Al

Comment: Can you please give a minimum working example of your code? That is, remove all of your code except the bare minimum that creates the plot with the problem. In particular, why are you using `imshow` as well as `contourf`? It looks like the values aren't being interpolated near the coast. Does changing the interpolation on `imshow` from `None` fix it?

Comment: Hi Spencer - i tried removing sections of the code line by line but the script wouldn't run with anything less than what i have posted, apart from removing 'm.imshow(data, origin='lower', interpolation='none')' but this increased the error of data around the coastline

Im not sure what i should replace 'none' with on interpolation

Cheers

Comment: Surely you can remove all the `print` statements, the lines commented out, the extra blank lines, and the title and colorbar commands at least. The less extraneous code there is, the easier it is to figure out what's causing the problem. Re: `imshow`, simply googling `matplotlib imshow` yields the official documentation [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow), which lists several other interpolation options to choose from.

Comment: sure I can I was just getting errors in the command terminal, ive now reduced it i think as much as i can. I also tried all of the interpolation options from the link but there was no visible improvement. I removed the interpolation that resulted in plot below.

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=d9a57a8 - 

http://pastebin.com/7NN388Fz

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, but can you please edit your original post to show the new code? Easier for folks to see than having to follow a link in your comment. Do you have access to the code that produced the original working plot (i.e. the bottom panel in your original link)? It looks like your original attempt (the top panel) is interpolating fine at some coastlines, so is there bad data at the locations (e.g. Britain) where it's not working?

Comment: Sure sorry about that. Unfortunately I don’t have access to the code on the working example as it was created by somebody i can no longer reach. I’m wondering if im using the correct Grib file because of the strange plotting North of Scotland

Comment: You should *absolutely* figure out if the data is correct before doing any further troubleshooting. I edited the code to make it (closer to) a minimum working example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)).

Comment: I really appreciate the help here and Im pretty sure its the right data now ive checked my plot against this one http://chart-1.msw.ms/wave/2014012712/750/1-1390878000-1.gif and they seem very close

My latest plot http://postimg.org/image/y53404t75/

Comment: No worries. Why are you changing `lat[0]` and `lon[0]`, and especially `lat[2]` and `lon[2]`? Try it without altering those values. The white near the continents isn't the only problem; the plot looks messed up within the oceans (e.g. north of Great Britain) as well. Also try removing the `rsphere=6371200` kwarg in your `Basemap` call; using the default value might help.

Comment: Thanks - ive tried playing with all of those values, the position of the map is dependent on lat[0] and lon[0] & lat[2] and lon[2] and removing the rsphere=6371200 kwarg made no difference. I have been researching the issue and i think its related to this line here `m.contourf(x, y, data, np.arange(0,9.9,0.1))` and creating a masked array as seen here http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Plotting-NOAA-data-td19588i20.html but im having problems understanding it being new to python and basemap

Comment: You can set the map position without altering the `lat` and `lon` arrays. Just set `llcrnrlat=42.00` directly in the `Basemap` call. Unless you *know* that the lat and lon values are wrong at those indices, you shouldn't change it -- the data corresponds to the specific lat and lon values they give, so changing the values will cause you to misrepresent the data (by plotting it at a different location than where it is meant to be).

Comment: Brilliant..some progress! That has got rid of the mess North of GB. Im still stuck with the white squares. Im sure that the data is there to be able to join the contours up. Now trying all sorts from the toolkit to no avail. I have updated code that is now plotting this image http://postimg.org/image/ouut0bk1v/

Comment: Good to hear. Can you somehow provide your `lat`, `lon`, and `data` arrays? I don't have `Nio` installed nor the time to do so, but I'd like to look at them.

Comment: Ive looked into this but i am away from my linux machine and cant seem to figure out on windows. Somebody has mentioned in another forum 

'It looks like with any reasonable contouring algorithm, this would
require interpolating into land regions, contouring, and then plotting
the land on top.  The key is the interpolation, not the plotting.  The
example you show might have been interpolated to a finer grid
everywhere, not just in the missing value regions.'

http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Plotting-NOAA-grib2-data-in-basemap-td42698.html

Comment: Just a remark: you might benefit from using [Iris](http://scitools.org.uk/iris/) instead of `Nio`/`basemap`.

Comment: Artifacts like the ones you see can also arise when the grid is not regular or monotonically increasing. Have you checked that? (`np.all(np.diff(lats, axis=0)>0))`, similar fro `lons`)